# Regd: Performance issue while connecting Oracle server through ODAC

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

I'm Using **ODAC** to connect the oracle server. while open the Oracleserver  connection it takes much time to open the endpoint connection. is there anyway to solve this performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, just saw this one.

Have you tried tracing the connection?  If you are using something like PL SQL Developer or Toad, they each have a performance tracking.  Use that to narrow down if it is that actual connection or weather it is the SQL.

If you are using EF, the linq is transformed into PL SQL that gets executed on the server.  Sometimes that translation does not go well so if you can capture what is being sent to the server, that will have narrow it down.